# Creating top layer to capture events

Tags: javascript, svg

I have some svg objcts drawing inside a div. To svg objects are attached handlers with stopPropagation method. Is there a way to add some top layer filling entire div to capture event before svg objects?

I can't use bubbling instead of a capture. I have to also listen on events that hit a div and not hit a svg object.

Comment: I need to catch event every time regardless if it hit other element or not.

Comment: Is it something like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwBvG?

Comment: Yes it is but it's work diffrent. Clicking on button should give only 'button' alert.
edit: Oh, I see. You changed capturing boolean. 
I need to capture event everytime i click inside a div but i also need another events when i click on button or outside (but still inside a div).

Comment: @Ilya Luzyanin thanks that was the answer I needed only another div outside in capture phase which will capture all events every time then inner div and other objects inside it will catch events using bubbling using also e.stopPropagation() on objects inside inner div gave me what I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome! Though I couldn't understand from your comments whether my solution worked for you and can I post it as an answer or not?

Comment: @achelon, I've posted an answer so you could accept it. Basic principles were correct, so I guess I've answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `addEventListener` has an option `useCapture` which is (according to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)):

> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree.

So, for example, if you have the following markup:

```
<div id="container">
  <button id="but">Hit Me!</button>
</div>
```

And following script:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var button = document.getElementById('but');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('button!');
}, false);
container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    alert('container!');
}, true);
```

Then all clicks of button will first go through `container` div event handler, despite of using `e.stopPropagation()` in button click event handler. Here is a [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwBvG), so you can play with it and get solution you want.